# Powershell script poor performance when creating a CSV file from JSON

Tags: json, csv, powershell

I have an performance issue with the below code. I want to parse some information from a JSON file to a CSV. The JSON itself has around 200k lines. The performance of this conversion is not good as it takes over 1h to process such a file.

I think the problem might be with the `Add-Content` function as I'm using a normal HDD for it. Could you please let me know if you see any improvements of the code or any changes that I could do?

```
$file = "$disk\TEMP\" + $mask
$res = (Get-Content $file) | ConvertFrom-Json
$file = "$disk\TEMP\result.csv"

Write-Host "Creating CSV from JSON" -ForegroundColor Green
Add-Content $file ("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}" -f "TargetId", "EventType", "UserId", "Username", "TimeStamp")

$l = 0
foreach ($line in $res) {
    if($line.EventType -eq 'DirectDownloadCompleted' -and $line.TargetDefinition -eq 'GOrder') { 
        #nothing here
    } elseif($line.EventType -eq 'DirectDownloadCompleted' -and $line.TargetDefinition -eq 'GFile') {
        Add-Content $file ("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}" -f
        $line.AssetId, $line.EventType, $line.UserId, $line.UserName, $line.TimeStamp)
        $l = $l + 1
    } else {
        Add-Content $file ("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}" -f $line.TargetId, $line.EventType, $line.UserId, $line.UserName, $line.TimeStamp)
        $l = $l + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want significantly better performance, I'd suggest using jq, which is easily installed on Windows.  To process a 200,000 line file using jq for the kind of task you describe shouldn't take more than 1s.  The jq download page is https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download; if you have chocolatey, the following should be suficient: choco install jq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, a few lessons here I think. First off, don't re-write the `Export-CSV` cmdlet. Instead convert your info into an array of objects, and output it all at once. This will make it so that you only have to write to the file once, which should increase your speed dramatically. Also, don't do `ForEach>If>IfElse>Else` when this function already exists in the `Switch` cmdlet. Try something like this:

```
$Results = Switch($res){
    {$_.EventType -eq 'DirectDownloadCompleted' -and $_.TargetDefinition -eq 'GOrder'}{Continue}
    {$_.EventType -eq 'DirectDownloadCompleted' -and $_.TargetDefinition -eq 'GFile'}{$_ | Select @{l='TargetId';e={$_.AssetId}},EventType,UserId,Username,TimeStamp;Continue}
    Default {$_ | Select TargetId,EventType,UserId,Username,TimeStamp}
}
$Results | Export-CSV $file -NoType
$l = $Results.Count
```

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks. This script reduced the time to 10 min. I went even further according to the suggestion from @sodawillow and created a separated C# console app which converts the JSON to CSV in 10 sec.